# JpaRepository findAll() will not return rows with null fields

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, entity, repository-pattern

I have a JPA Repository like so:

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentTagsViewRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentTagsView, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DocumentTagsView> {
```

And an entity like so:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(DocumentTagsView.class)
@Table(name="document_tags_view", schema="pdf_processing")
public class DocumentTagsView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8222170971385430496L;

    @Id
    @Column
    String vid;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    Long did;

    @Column
    Long tid;

    @Column
    String text;

public DocumentTagsView () {}

public String getVid() {
    return vid;
}

public void setVid(String vid) {
    this.vid = vid;
}

public Long getDid() {
    return did;
}

public void setDid(Long did) {
    this.did = did;
}

public Long getTid() {
    return tid;
}

public void setTid(Long tid) {
    this.tid = tid;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DocumentTagsView [vid=" + vid + ", did=" + did + ", tid=" + tid + ", text=" + text + "]";
}
```

My table has 5 records, two with null values in the did column:

```
vid                                     did     tid text
a31a1aa8-f29a-11e9-ba9d-d8cb8abfa8f6    2       6   A
a31a1a79-f29a-11e9-ba9d-d8cb8abfa8f6    2       4   B
a31a1ad2-f29a-11e9-ba9d-d8cb8abfa8f6    2       7   C
a31a19e8-f29a-11e9-ba9d-d8cb8abfa8f6    (null)  1   D
a31a1a57-f29a-11e9-ba9d-d8cb8abfa8f6    (null)  3   E
```

When I execute a DocumentTagsViewRepository.findAll(), I get a list with 5 positions, but the last two are null.  I would expect to get two DocumentTagsView objects in those positions, but with the did value null.

How do I get all five records in my findAll list?

Comment: ur id type is ````string```` and ur repository is ````JpaRepository<DocumentTagsView, Long>```` change ````Long```` to ````String```` and try again

Comment: Good catch!  Changed it; no dice.

Comment: Can you the code that demonstrates that `findAll()` returns `null`-elements?

Comment: why u use ````@IdClass(DocumentTagsView.class)````?

Comment: @hosseinrasekhi, that was it!  Leftover copy-paste from a different class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u are using `@IdClass` annotation that use for composite PK and  jpa ignore the null value.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you might have to create getters and setters for you Entity. Not sure if Hibernate or whatever ORM you're using will know how to populate the Entity otherwise.

Comment: Thanks!  I have getters and setters; didn't want to include as they're not "special".